# web.eth.call() returns a revert even when the transaction is success

Tags: web3js, etherscan

I have this snippet to test if `web3.eth.call()` can check if a pending transaction will revert in advance.

```
web3.eth.call(tx, "pending")
.then(result => { console.log(count, "Passed!") })
.catch(revertReason => console.log(count, "Reason: ", revertReason ))
```

Then there are some calls on transactions that return revert error like
`{code: -32000, message: "err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value (supplied gas 164340)"}`

or

`Fail with error 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT`

When I check into etherscan they were success.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction execution result depends on the context.

Execution simulation with eth_call or estimateGas don't necessarily imply it will succeed or fail.

The uniswap transaction appears failing with insufficient amount while pending. If before being mined a third party deposit enough funds it will succeed.

Similarly a transaction in pending might fail with not enough funds, but another pending transaction may increase those funds and allow the transaction to be mined.

The pending pool changes frequently so at any moment a node might not contain all pending transactions.

Comment: does that mean the`web3.eth.call` isn't really good at estimating if a pending tx will fail or not?

Comment: @Marr It might work in many cases, but for certain type of contract it might not work. If a transaction depends on the contract state, then any change between eth_call and the transaction mined might affect the transaction final result.