# Using ganache mainnet-fork, why does a contract method call fail, but a transaction succeeds?

Tags: web3.py, ganache

I am using Ganache mainnet-fork to test my smart contracts prior to actual deployment. When I use `call` on a contract, it fails. However, sending the transaction succeeds. Why is this?

It is not just "reverting", it is throwing a specific error message fairly deep in the contract. So it's executing most of it, but then failing out.

---

I found [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/92026/63322) which sounds really similar to what I'm seeing, but the answer is relating to state changes on the blockchain (txs occurring between the `call` and the actual transaction). For me, on a local mainnet-fork, I don't think this is possible; I'm the only one interacting with the blockchain.

---

I've tested this using both web3py and brownie (which just wraps web3py). Specifically in brownie, this looks like:

```py
my_contract.myFunction.call(*args, {'from': me})  # Fails, throws an error
my_contract.myFunction(*args, {'from': me})  # Succeeds
```

Comment: What's the error message? Can you show the code executed?

Comment: @Ismael It's a custom revert message (throwing on a `<` comparison). I'll see if I can get a simplified example that stands alone and shows what I mean.